# Captured video being saved to different folder than specified

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm making an app that let's you either capture photo/video, or choose an existing photo/video before sending. I set up the directory to save the files in here:

```
String appName = Main.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appName);
```

and I name the files here

```
File mediaFile;
Date now = new Date();
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(now);
String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator;
if(mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO){
    mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
} else if(mediaType==MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
    mediaFile = new File(path + "VID_" + timestamp + ".mp4");
}
```

So it's saving my pictures under `/storage/emulated/0/pictures/(app name)` with correct timestamped format. However, my videos are being saved to `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA` and are just being named `VIDEO0073`, `VIDEO00074`, etc. I tried changing the directory name to `MOVIES` instead of `PICTURES` or `DCIM`, but there is no effect. I'm on an HTC One running Android 4.3

Comment: Are you using [Camera Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)? Have you specified the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`?

Comment: Yes and yes, for both picture and video capture, but like I said, only pictures save in the right format in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that occurs on certain devices including the HTC One. If you include your code where you declare your video Intent I could more precisely answer the question, but basically, after you declare your Intent for the video (not image), get your Uri like so:

videoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

In this case the video will be saved in the /storage/emulated/0/video folder instead of the pictures or dcim folders you mentioned above.